# Where do I download Android Kernel

Tags: android, gcc

I am trying to download BuildUtils and GCC for custom compiling, however, everytime I try I get...

```
jackie@jackie-Latitude-E6410:~/Development/Code/Google/toolchain$     ~/Development/Google/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r6b/build/tools/download-toolchain-sources.sh ./
Using git clone prefix: git://android.git.kernel.org/toolchain
downloading sources for toolchain/binutils
ERROR: Could not clone git://android.git.kernel.org/toolchain/binutils.git ?
```

Now I know there was some issue with kernel.org getting hacked can anyone tell me where the new location is?

Answer (score 0):

Android removed there source form kernel.org, as I recall from the news. It would start hosting it on their own servers. See: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.

But I don't know if this also applies to the utils you are trying to download.

Comment: Nope can't find toolchain in this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Google Source](http://android.googlesource.com/).

Answer (score 0):

FYI Here is what I was looking for...

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gcc.git
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gmp.git
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/build.git
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/mpc.git
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/mpfr.git
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gdb.git
```